# Spark: Equivalent to not in

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, subquery, sql-in

I have a where clause in Spark SQL that for some reason doesn't return any records. I think it doesn't work and so I would like to ask what would be equivalent to it?

```
SELECT
  c.client_id,
  current_date() as insert_date
FROM
  CLIENT_SUB c
WHERE
  (c.client_id, insert_date) not in (SELECT client_id, insert_date from CLIENT_SUBSCRIBER_CONTRACT)
```

I heard I could do it with a join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend `not exists`: it is `null`-safe, while `not it` isn't - and it usually scales better, too.

I am also suspiscious about the reference to `insert_date`: do you really mean that, or you actually want `current_date()`?

```
select cs.client_id, current_date() as insert_date
from client_sub cs
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from client_subscriber_contract csc
    where 
        csc.client_id = c.client_id 
        and csc.insert_date = cs.insert_date
        -- or, maybe: csc.insert_date = current_date()
)
```

For performance, consider an index on `client_subscriber_contract(client_id, insert_date)`.

Comment: Thanks, your solution works. I was under the impression that there is no indexing supported in spark. What's the command you had in mind?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have null values in the output of your subquery because `not in` doesn't output anything when matched against values containing nulls. Try

```
not in (select client_id, insert_date 
        from CLIENT_SUBSCRIBER_CONTRACT
        where coalesce(client_id, insert_date) is not null)
```

I recommend looking into `not exists` for your purpose though